# get rid of : AllCapsTransformationMethod 'caller did not enable length changes'

Tags: android

I noticed many time this Warning in my logs and I want to know how to get rid of it.

I understand it comes from [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/method/AllCapsTransformationMethod.java) where the AllCapsTransformationMethod  has a disable state.

- How to solve it ? Where should I call the method `setLengthChangesAllowed(boolean allowLengthChanges)` ?
- Why does it appear ?
- How much impact does it have on the processing (I am running on very very low memory devices) ?

Thanks.

PS : if you know better tags, I will add them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `setLengthChangesAllowed(boolean)` will be called by `TextView` in `setTransformationMethod(TransformationMethod)`. The value of the boolean flag is evaluated like this (I only checked API 18): `mAllowTransformationLengthChange = !isTextSelectable() && !(mText instanceof Editable);`.

So if the text is selectable or editable (for example your component is an `EditText`), the `AllCapsTransformationMethod` will be ignored and you will get the warning message `W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text`.

To hopefully answer your questions:

- Use non-selectable, non-editable text components if you wish the transform to be applied, or don't set `android:textAllCaps` to true for editable/selectable text - that should get rid of the warning. You cannot really call `setLengthChangesAllowed(boolean)` unless you use reflection voodoo which might work or not, break things and make your code harder to maintain.
- See explanation above. I hope it helps
- Getting the warning basically means you have a useless `AllCapsTransformationMethod` in memory which ocasionally produces that warning but otherwise does nothing. The performance impact should be minimal, tending towards zero. It's probably best to manually set your editable/selectable text to caps instead of applying the `textAllCaps` attribute with no effect.